# Enzyme not shallow rendering child

Tags: reactjs, chai, enzyme

I am trying to test that a child component exists by shallow-rendering it with Enzyme. However, it does not appear to be getting past the return of the component and instead shallow-renders `<undefined />`.

## MainComponentContainer.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class'
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes'
import MainComponent from './MainComponent'
import {addSelection} from '../../actions/betslip'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export const MainComponentContainter = createReactClass({
  displayName: 'MainComponentCont',
  propTypes: {
    displayMode: PropTypes.string,
    other: ImmutablePropTypes.map,
    addSelection: PropTypes.func,
    prices: ImmutablePropTypes.map,
    selections: ImmutablePropTypes.map,
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.other.valueSeq().map(this.renderMain)}
      </div>
    )
  },

  renderMain(other) {
    const yesOutcome = other.get('markets').first().get('outcomes').first()
    const newPrice = this.props.prices.getIn([yesOutcome.get('id'), 'price'])

    if (newPrice) {
      return (
        <MainComponent key={other.get('id')}
                    ...some other props/>
      )
    }
    return null
  }
})

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return (state) => {
    const displayMode = state.ui.get('displayMode')
    const selections = state.stp.get('selections')
    const prices = state.catalog.get('prices')
    const other = state.catalog.get('other')

    return {
      displayMode,
      other,
      prices,
      selections,
    }
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addSelection,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponentContainer)
```

## MainComponent.js

This just basically returns another component to the above component.

```
return (
    <div style={[styles.container, styles.container[displayMode]]}>
      <div style={[styles.logo, styles.logo[displayMode]]}>
        {renderLogo(displayMode, quoteExtraLogo)}
        {displayMode === 'mobile' &&
          renderButton({displayMode, selected, suspended, clickHandler})}
      </div>
      <div style={[styles.content, styles.content[displayMode]]}>
        <h2 style={[styles.headline, styles.headline[displayMode]]}>
          {title}
        </h2>
        <div style={[styles.offer, styles.offer[displayMode]]}>
          <div style={[styles.details, styles.details[displayMode]]}>
            <p style={[styles.market, styles.market[displayMode]]}>
              {text}
            </p>
            <div>
              <p style={[styles.improvedOdds, styles.improvedOdds[displayMode]]}>
                <span style={styles.improvedOddsAt}>a</span> {newPrice}
              </p>
              <p style={[styles.previousOdds, styles.previousOdds[displayMode]]}>
                invece di{' '}
                <span className="strikethrough">
                  {oldPrice}
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {displayMode === 'desktop' &&
            renderButton({displayMode, selected, suspended, clickHandler})}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

## Test

```
describe.only('MainComponentContainer Component', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
    addSelectionSpy = sinon.spy()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  function getOutput({
    displayMode = 'mobile',
    other = mockData,
    addSelection = spy,
    prices = pricesMock,
    selections = selectionsMock,
  } = {}) {

    return shallow(
      <MainComponentContainer
        displayMode = {displayMode}
        other = {mockData}
        addSelection = {addSelection}
        prices = {prices}
        selections = {selections}
      />
    )
  }

  it('should include a MainComponent component', () => {
    const pb = getOutput().find('MainComponent')
    expect(pb.length).to.equal(1)
  })
```

When doing the above test (should include a `MainComponent` component), I get the following error:

> ```
>  AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1
>  + expected - actual
>
>  -0
>  +1
> ```

However I have logged out `getOutput().debug()`, and it returns `<div><undefined /></div>`.

Comment: Can you make a less verbose example that reproduces problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `shallow` renderer is intentionally limited to operating on only the root component so as to make the test more isolated. In the case of decorators or "wrapped" components like this, the wrapped component is not what we want to test. Since `MainComponentContainer` is a HOC, you face this problem.

There are two ways to get around this problem, either

First export the undecorated component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponentContainer)
export {MainComponentContainer as ComponentContainer};
```

and test like

```
return shallow(
  <ComponentContainer
    displayMode = {displayMode}
    other = {mockData}
    addSelection = {addSelection}
    prices = {prices}
    selections = {selections}
  />
)
```

or use `.dive`

```
  it('should include a MainComponent component', () => {
    const pb = getOutput().dive().find('MainComponent')
    expect(pb.length).to.equal(1)
  })
```

Comment: OK, but will this not still result in the child component on `<MainComponentContainer>` not being `<undefined />`?

Comment: did you try both the methods??

Comment: I will try, but I am just seeking a little explanation. Is it necessary to export the `MainComponentContainer` as `ComponentContainer` how is that different to doing `export const MainComponentContainer`?

Comment: No its not different, you could use `export const MainComponentContainer` . Only thing is that you need to export the unconnected container

Comment: OK, so I'm doing that already, but why does `shallow` on that component result in rendering an `<undefined />` child? So, when I log out the component by doing `console.log(getOutput().debug())` it shallows `<div><undefined /></div>`

Comment: I don't see you doing that in your question, as I said export the component without connect and import is as a named import then like `import {MainComponentContainer} form '/path'`, I guess you did not import as a named container, even when you exported it right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155894/discussion-between-jbd-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `dive()` exactly what I needed